# Undo your suggested edits on someone else's question before a review takes place

Tags: support, suggested-edits

This comes with a personal experience I recently had.

I made a suggested edit to someone else's question by correcting the spellings and by having a look at the question again, I found out that it has got many downvotes which made me wanted to undo my suggested edit as I felt that it is not needed there anymore. But I did not find any of such options to achieve that.

My suggested edit also got rejected later on and my concerns are;

- Is there an option to undo your suggested edit before a review
  takes place? If so please be kind enough to point that out.
- Is this an option which you must earn with your reputation?

Comment: If you click "Edit" again, you can make any changes you like and they will be merged with your current suggested edit. That's, of course, as long as the current suggested edit hasn't been approved/rejected yet.

Comment: Focus your suggested edits in questions that are already of good quality, but that just require a bit of polishing, and this stops being a concern.

Comment: Your edit was probably rejected because you didn't remove "Good morning" and "Thank you", not because of the question quality. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/3021#3021)

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I understand.. so apart from manually going through all the changes and undo one by one, there's no option to undo all at once. Thanks

Comment: @yivi Thanks and I will make a note of it. I only wanted to help him out since he was a new contributor who was probably not much aware of the quality standards.